# Full screen video work partially in firefox but not chrome

Tags: javascript, html, video, fullscreen

The video container broadcasting a live video stream using webrtc.

initially the fullscreen video is disabled. after user click the setup broadcast button the stop/fullscreen btn will be enabled.

Fullscreen work partially in firefox but it does not work in chrome..
below is the screenshot in firefox video only appear in the top left corner.

[image]

FullScreen source Code

```
<button id="fullscreeniframe" class="button" disabled>Fullscreen</button>

document.getElementById('fullscreeniframe').disabled = false;

var videosContainer = document.getElementById('videos-container') 

document.getElementById('fullscreeniframe').onclick = function() {

                if (videosContainer.requestFullscreen) {
                videosContainer.requestFullscreen();
              } else if (videosContainer.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                videosContainer.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
              } else if (videosContainer.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                videosContainer.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
                alert("ABCD");
                // nid to call scaleVideos();
              }
            };
```

I also have a scaleVideos function. not sure if it interrupt my fullscreen code? or do i have to make use of it? if so how?

My ScaleVideo Function code

```
function scaleVideos() {
            var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video'),
                length = videos.length,
                video;

            var mydiv = document.getElementById("LiveConferencing");
            var curr_width = mydiv.offsetWidth;
            var curr_height = mydiv.offsetHeight;

            var minus = 130;
            var windowHeight = curr_height;
            var windowWidth = curr_width;
            var windowAspectRatio = windowWidth / windowHeight;
            var videoAspectRatio = 4 / 3;
            var blockAspectRatio;
            var tempVideoWidth = 0;
            var maxVideoWidth = 0;

            for (var i = length; i > 0; i--) {
                blockAspectRatio = i * videoAspectRatio / Math.ceil(length / i);
                if (blockAspectRatio <= windowAspectRatio) {
                    tempVideoWidth = videoAspectRatio * windowHeight / Math.ceil(length / i);
                } else {
                    tempVideoWidth = windowWidth / i;
                }
                if (tempVideoWidth > maxVideoWidth)
                    maxVideoWidth = tempVideoWidth;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                video = videos[i];
                if (video)
                    video.width = maxVideoWidth - minus;
            }
        }
```

Comment: As far as I know, html5 video don't need scaling for fullscreen... Though I have no experience with live-streams...

Comment: in Firefox there a fullscreen video control but not in chrome.. there why i am creating a btn to make the video full screen..

Comment: But you called the fullscreen method for webkit (Chrome)... What happens if you leave the `scaleVideos` function out?

Comment: i commented function scaleVideos() and it still doesn't display in full screen. i believe function scaleVideos() is use to define the size of the video container? not really sure about this as i took over this project from someone else..

Comment: Not so sure either. I always use html5 videos without fullscreen-container. Just pick the video element itself and request it fullscreen. Maybe the difference is the stream, or maybe you got some codec problem? (ogg vs mp4 vs webm)? Sorry, running out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between Webkit and Gecko implementations of the HTML5 full screen feature. Gecko automatically adds CSS rules `"width: 100%; height: 100%"` to adjust it to the screen dimensions. Webkit however, centers the element with its original dimensions over a black background.
To achieve the same behaviour on Webkit, add these CSS rules to your element:

```
#yourElementId:-webkit-full-screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```